# Better way to find common words in a tuple?

Tags: python, string, tuples

I completed an exercise in which I found and returned the common words between two strings in alphabetical order as a string, separated by commas.  Though I was able to do it correctly, I am wondering if there is a better way.  Better can be defined however you define it.

```
def return_common(first, second):
    first = first.split(',')
    second = second.split(',')
    newList = ",".join(list(set(first) & set(second)))
    #newList = list(newList)
    newList = newList.split(',')
    newList = sorted(newList)
    newList = ",".join(newList)
    return newList

return_common("one,two,three", "four,five,one,two,six,three")
#above returns 'one,three,two'
```

Comment: Why do you do `",".join(list(set...` only to do `.split(',')` on the next line? Couldn't you just do `return ",".join(sorted(list(set(first) & set(second))))`?

Comment: Just remove a few lines, you first use ",".join to make newList and then immediately split it again...

Comment: Also, what if there are duplicate words?

Comment: The core of your algorithm is `set(first) & set(second)`. I think this is the most accepted way of finding common elements in 2 groups (which immediately comes from the `intersection of sets` definition). The rest can be cleaned, notably the `join/split/sort/join again` routine

Comment: @Bill : that's what sets are for.

Comment: Thank you! If I'm reading your responses correctly, I could turn the entire tuple into one sorted list in one line.  I split it apart so that I could evaluate each word separately

Comment: @njzk2 Obviously. I meant what if you had `'one, one, two, three'` and `'one, one, two, two, three'`.  Should the algorithm account for the repeated items, returning `'one, one, two, three'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code can be shortened(into a line) like this -

```
def return_common(first, second):
    return ",".join(sorted(set(first.split(","))&set(second.split(","))))
```

Testing it -

```
>>> return_common("one,two,three", "four,five,one,two,six,three")
'one,three,two'
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic method is good but you are doing too much work. Repeated joins and splits, and turning things into lists that don't need to be. And do you need the result to be sorted?

You could do just

```
def return_common(first, second):
    common_words = set(first.split(",")) & set(second.split(","))
    return ",".join(common_words)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to extend your question. Here is my answer.

```
def return_common(*data):
    common_words = reduce(lambda a,b:a&b, map(lambda x: set(x.split(",")), data))
    return ",".join(common_words)
```

example:

```
>>> return_common("two,three", "four,five,one,two,six,three", "three"):
'three'
```